# Is the Visual Studio 2008 Object Test Bench useful for anything?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, object-test-bench

Is the Visual Studio 2008 Object Test Bench useful for anything?  Maybe I'm missing something but aside from a flashy version of the immediate window, it doesn't seem like a developer would actually use it for anything.

*(And how many people knew it existed in the first place?!)*

In case you're wondering, the 'Object Test Bench' is located under 'View / Other Windows' in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never heard of it until you mentioned it - thanks for bringing it to my attention.

I do think it's useful. If I want to see how "stuff" works I usually drop my code into LINQPad and see what sort of results I get by doing a Dump() on the resulting object. Only problem is that you have to copy your whole class and supporting classes in there to get anything more than trivial stuff to work. Also, there's no intellisense in LINQPad.

This looks like it can replace what I use LINQPad for. Quick and dirty playing with the objects.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can use it for load/stress testing, but my only exposure to it was a quick demo way back at the Ready To Launch event for VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

Object Test Bench is good for Unit Testing your code and pretty much lightweight. It exists in VS2005 too. I prefer NUNIT which is more powerful